# NavigationView below Action Bar with AppBarLayout

Tags: android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, drawerlayout, android-appbarlayout, navigationview

I want to do NavigationView below Action Bar like this but shadow don't let me to do:

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evbms.png)

Here is my **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        // HERE IS FOR PAGE CODING, LAYOUTS, INFOS ETC.

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The main goal is removing shadow which is covering AppBarLayout (NOT ALL OF THEM, JUST UNCOVER APPBAR). Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for answer to this question.

Not a perfect solution. But you can try putting a margin_top equals actionbarsize in navigationView.

["android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"] : - you can put this attribute in NavigationView

But sometimes it doesnt solve the entire issue. Because it does not account for status bar height.